# While developing Clojure, is running the dev environment with npm incompatible with Emacs Cider?

Tags: npm, emacs, clojure, reagent, cider

I am new to Clojure and not a pro in Javascript. I am watching the free part of the course on [Reagent](https://www.jacekschae.com/view/courses/learn-reagent-free/21667-setup/57005-03-state).

Following the instructions on the course's [repo](https://github.com/jacekschae/learn-reagent-course-files), after doing the `git clone` and the `npm install`, the author indicates running `$ npm run dev`. Everything works fine. I can see the app on my `http://localhost:3000/`.

Since I am a heavy user of Emacs, I decided to start [Cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), an emacs package that makes Emacs an IDE for Clojure. Thus, I would do interactive programming with REPL.

After executing in Emacs `cider-jack-in`, an error is returned. Emacs indicates:

> error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: shadow-cljs - config: /home/pedro/projects/learn-reagent-course-files/giggin/shadow-cljs.edn
> shadow-cljs - connected to server
> server already running

While it is not possible to do `cider-jack-in` after `npm run dev`, **it is** possible to **successfully** use `cider-jack-in`. To do so, I just need to exit everything and without dealing with npm, simply execute `cider-jack-in` on the repo.

Why is this happening? Is Emacs cider incompatible with `npm run dev`? Incompatible with a server already running?

Concerning the error message content, what is the relation between Cider, the npm process, and shadow-cljs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment on any Cider/Emacs specific things since I don't use it myself. I can however attempt to maybe clear up what is is doing:

`npm run dev` just runs `npx shadow-cljs watch app` (see `package.json` `"scripts"`). It is just an alias, making it a little shorter. So, it starts shadow-cljs and begins the `app` build compilation and keeps watching for changes.

`cider-jack-in` on the other hand I believe also starts a fresh new JVM, which will be entirely independent and not aware or connected to the shadow-cljs processes started via `npm run dev`.

It is possible to just use `shadow-cljs` from the REPL you get from `cider-jack-in`, but I don't know any specifics about what `cider-jack-in` may already be doing for you. Maybe the [docs on REPL use](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_clojure_repl) can provide some help?

You can instead also just skip `cider-jack-in` and instead have Cider connect to the `shadow-cljs` instances started by `npm run dev`. I believe that command is `cider-connect`.