# Why is shadow-cljs returning this error message on "Stale Output"? How to guarantee the watch for this building is running?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop, shadow-cljs

I am new to Clojure and not a pro in Javascript. I am watching the free part of the course on [Reagent](https://www.jacekschae.com/view/courses/learn-reagent-free).

Following the instructions on the course's [repo](https://github.com/jacekschae/learn-reagent-course-files), after doing the `git clone` and the `npm install`, the author indicates running `$ npm run dev`. Everything *seems* to work fine. I can see the app on my `http://localhost:3000/`.

The favicon with the app's logo and its name is loaded on the corner of the browser's tab:

[image]

However, on the bottom of the web page, there is this error message from `shadow-cljs`:

> shadow-cljs - Stale Output! Your loaded JS was not produced by the
> running shadow-cljs instance. Is the watch for this build running?

[image]

Why is this happening? How should I fix it?
How to guarantee that the watch for this building is running?

Is there a simple command to run on terminal to check this?

**Obs. 1**: If this is relevant, my operational system is NixOS and this is my [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config/blob/main/configuration.nix).

**Obs. 2**: I am not sure if this question is connected to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056828/while-developing-clojure-is-running-the-dev-environment-with-npm-incompatible-w) on `npm` and `Cider` (Emacs IDE for Clojure) that happened while working with this same repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that this is due to you running `npm run dev` AND `cider-jack-in`.

I don't use emacs, so I'm not exactly sure what `cider-jack-in` does, but I believe it launches a new JVM. Since the `npm run dev` also did that you end up with two running JVMs, which also means two running `shadow-cljs` instances. That is not ideal and they will start interfering with each other leading to errors such as yours.

So, either you run `npm run dev` and use emacs to connect to that server. `cider-connect` or whatever is called should do that.

Or you don't run `npm run dev` at all and instead only `cider-jack-in` and then start the `watch` from the REPL.

Don't forget to first kill all java processes that might be running for that project. As long as there is more than one `shadow-cljs` process running for the project things will be weird.

Comment: Thank you! How do you start the watch from the REPL?

Comment: `(shadow.cljs.devtools.api/watch :app)` if the server already started. Otherwise first `(shadow.cljs.devtools.server/start!)`. Each may need a `(require ...)` first.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I clicked on the build link BEFORE it has compiled. In which case, the link is displaying a previously compiled version, not the live version, and "watch" on code changes doesn't work either. Just wait for your terminal output to say "compiled" before clicking on the link.